# Using nodejs fluent-ffmpeg to stream to icecast server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to make an api call to express which calls ffmpeg outputing a stream to icecast.

I can do this with `child_process`, but have found `fluent-ffmpeg` for nodejs.

If I add

```
.save('icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8000/test')
```

I get an invalid argument error, and if I use

```
.output('icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8000/test')
```

I get no error, a correct response to the calling web page , but no `ffmpeg` process.

Does anyone know if `fluent-ffmpeg` outputs to `icecast`.

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
  app.get('/ffmpeg', function(req, res) {
    var ffmpegPath = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';
    proc = new ffmpeg('/home/russ/radio_audio/fore/BaBeL74.wav')
      .output('icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8000/test');
    proc.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
    res.send('ok');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try icy module for using icecast in nodejs

---

[icy module nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icy)

Comment: Thanks for the response , as far as i can workout this module accepts a stream and will stream to stdout / inject metadata.  I need to encode and stream result to icecast, so not sure if it will help.

Answer (score 0):

long time since I worked with "fluent-ffmpeg", have you tried to use "writeToStream" function? Something like:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
app.get('/ffmpeg', function(req, res) {
  var ffmpegPath = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg';
  new ffmpeg('/home/russ/radio_audio/fore/BaBeL74.wav')
   .writeToStream(res, function(retcode, error){
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  });
});
```

Maybe this link can you https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/124

Comment: Thanks for the reply , and sorry for the delay in responding.
I desided to go with a child_process bash script in the end as i have a complicated ffmpeg script which i would have to add options to fluent-ffmpeg for.